# Grease Pencil Object Channels not Showing, can't see frames

Tags: grease-pencil

I opened up a project and I wanted to edit one of my Grease Pencil objects-- but it's not showing any of its layers in the Grease Pencil Channels. I clicked on another GP object in the same project and it showed the layers no problem. I unlinked all of the objects parented to the GP object in question, opened it up in a new file, made sure it didn't have anything animated, wasn't in too many collections, made sure I'm in the right menu, in draw mode. I can STILL draw, but I won't be able to see it make the new keyframes, or edit the keyframes at all. I'm going insane, I can't figure out why I can't see the channels for this object.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the option to "Only show selected" enabled.  It's the blue arrowhead in the set of icons on the right of the graph editor.

[image: Graph Editor showing "Only show selected" is enabled.]

If you disable it, then every F-curve you've created by adding keyframes will show up in the graph editor.

If you select an object that you've added F-curves to, by creating keyframes for them, then all of the F-curves for that object will show up in the Graph Editor.